# Check the continuity of $f(x,y) = \cases{ \text{sgn}(x) \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2} & for $0 < |y| < |x|$ \cr 0 & otherwise. }$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

In this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/105773/42411), Robert Israel suggests the following function.
$$f(x,y) = \cases{ \text{sgn}(x) \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2} & for $0 < |y| < |x|$  \cr 0 & otherwise.
}$$

However, I am wondering whether this function $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: $f(1,\frac 1 n)=1-\frac1 n \to 1$ whereas $f(1,0)=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. So the function is not continuous at $(1,0)$.